# Is it possible in google cloud web client to create an instance from image in different project?

Tags: image, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have several projects in gcloud, call them e.g. "staging-project" and "production-project". I have created an image, call it "stagign-image-1" in "staging-project", which I use for new instances. And I would like to use this image in "production-project" as well.

As far as I know, it is possible to do it using gcloud command line tool - you log there using your private google account, which has access to both projects and do:

`gcloud config set project "production-project`

`gcloud compute instances create production-instance-from-staging-image --image staging-image-1 --image-project staging-project`

This works fine for me, but I have few colleagues who don't like command line so much. So is there a way how to achieve this in the gcloud web console? When I list images in production-project, I simply do not see the staging-image-1 and I found no way how to select it. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--image-project` is not currently supported in the developers console.

An issue has been filed to fix that. Thanks.