# Opensuse Images No Longer Visible in Default Compute Instance

Tags: gcloud

All,

Opensuse Images are not listed as Active in GCloud but are showing up in the gloud commands in my project.... the Opensuse project is not mine... can I link to someone else's

[Gcloud shell output

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please review your question? I think something got cut off when you posted it. I can't tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies I found a suitable answer:

[Is it possible in google cloud web client to create an instance from image in different project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37862718/is-it-possible-in-google-cloud-web-client-to-create-an-instance-from-image-in-di)

The Command syntax is from the Gloud Shell is:

gcloud compute instances create production-instance-from-staging-image --image staging-image-1 --image-project staging-project

For Opensuse you have to link to their staging project which is opensuse-project which includes the images. The exact command is attached.....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beXU1.png)

Comment: When I use Gcloud Compute Functions from the console when you go to create instances now, Opensuse is no longer a default image option in every Gcloud project when it used to be back in June of 2016. As a result its much harder to use Opensuse. You either have to create a custom image on your own (which is difficult in Gcloud) or you have to create an instance from the Opensuse project which requires a command line task.

Answer (score 0):

The Original Question is how to build Gcloud Instances on OpenSUSE with the Console. It used to be a default option in each project.

To achieve this you have to do two things:
**1) Find the Opensuse Projects which are in fact documented in Google's online support but requires a gloud command to find the specific images.**

The command is : 
gloud compute images list --project opensuse-cloud --no-standard-images

**2) You have to specifically provision to your project from the opensuse-cloud project**

gcloud compute instances create your-instancename --image image-namefrom#1 --image-project opensuse-cloud